# Taking input from editbox as displaying the result

Tags: c++, string, mfc, char, integer

I am currently working on an MFC C++ program that takes a mathematical expression as input and displays the result. But I am having trouble reading from the editbox. The code for taking in input and displaying it is as below:

```
{   

    char input[50];
    sprintf_s(input, "%d", IDC_EDIT1); 
    len = strlen(input);
    ...
    ...
    CString s;
    s.Format(_T("%.2f"), mCurVal);
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, s);

}
```

IDC_EDIT1 is the input from the editbox. I want to change that to a char so I can be able to call each character and compute the mathematical operation. The middle part I committed works well so I tried everything to see where the problem is and seems like it is in the first 3 lines. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `sprintf_s(input, "%d", IDC_EDIT1);` - That doesn't make sense. What's that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I used sprintf at first to change the int to char but changed it to sprintf_s because it kept giving me warnings. Sprintf also outputs the same. I get 1000 as the output no matter what number I input

Comment: `IDC_EDIT1` is the resource ID of the editbox (in the resource file), and does not have anything to do with the value.

Comment: Yes, I want to get the value of what I inserted in the editbox that is why I am using the ID IDC_EDIT1. Isn't that what I should do?

Comment: No, that's not how you access the control's *contents*. You already know `SetDlgItemText`. To do the inverse you would call [`GetDlgItemText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#getdlgitemtext). Though, with MFC, you probably wouldn't want to manually do that anyway. Just bind a `CString` variable to the control and have DDX do everything else. Realistically, there's zero chance for someone that doesn't understand the Windows API to use MFC proficiently.

Comment: I am using MFC today for the first time but thank you anyway for replying. I have figured it out~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
{   
    CString input;
    GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, input);
    len = input.GetLength();
    ...
    CString s;
    s.Format(_T("%.2f"), mCurVal);
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, s);
}
```

Forget char arrays like `char input[50];` if you're using MFC, you can use `CString` almost all the time instead.